# Return Only Duplicate Rows with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a **bookings** table and I am trying show unique guests who booked the same room.

`booking_id | check_in_date | check_out_date | guest_id | room_number
------------+---------------+----------------+----------+-------------
       1001 | 2018-01-01    | 2018-01-03     |        1 |         702
       1002 | 2018-01-01    | 2018-01-05     |        2 |        1104
       1003 | 2018-01-05    | 2018-01-07     |        4 |         509
       1004 | 2018-01-05    | 2018-01-07     |        4 |         511
       1005 | 2018-01-07    | 2018-01-08     |        2 |         404
       1006 | 2018-01-07    | 2018-01-09     |        1 |        1104
       1007 | 2018-01-10    | 2018-01-12     |        2 |         509
       1008 | 2018-01-15    | 2018-01-18     |        6 |         404
       1009 | 2018-01-15    | 2018-01-18     |        6 |         406
       1010 | 2018-01-15    | 2018-01-17     |        4 |         511
       1011 | 2018-01-20    | 2018-01-22     |        2 |         509
       1012 | 2018-01-23    | 2018-01-25     |        4 |         511`

So I'm attemping to return:

room_number 404 (room booked by unique guest_id 2 & 6)

room_number 509 (room booked by unique guest_id 2 & 4)

room_number 1104 (room booked by unique guest_id 1 & 2)

The closest I got was with this statement:

`SELECT room_number, guest_id, COUNT(room_number) 
  FROM bookings 
  GROUP BY room_number, guest_id 
  ORDER BY room_number;`

Which returns:

`room_number | guest_id | count
-------------+----------+-------
         404 |        2 |     1
         404 |        6 |     1
         406 |        6 |     1
         509 |        4 |     1
         509 |        2 |     2
         511 |        4 |     3
         702 |        1 |     1
        1104 |        2 |     1
        1104 |        1 |     1`

I need to remove the room_number that appear once (room_number 406, 511 & 702).

Comment: Hint: use`EXISTS(subquery)`

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/4a1f7/37)

**Query 1**:

```
select a.room_number,a.guest_id, b.count 
FROM bookings a JOIN
(
SELECT room_number, count (*) as count 
    FROM bookings 
  GROUP BY room_number 
  HAVING count ( DISTINCT guest_id ) > 1
  ) b ON a.room_number = b.room_number
ORDER BY room_number
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/4a1f7/37/0)**:

```
| room_number | guest_id | count |
|-------------|----------|-------|
|         404 |        6 |     2 |
|         404 |        2 |     2 |
|         509 |        2 |     3 |
|         509 |        4 |     3 |
|         509 |        2 |     3 |
|        1104 |        2 |     2 |
|        1104 |        1 |     2 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this. (This query works in SQL SERVER)

```
SELECT a_tabla.guest_id,COUNT(a_tabla.room_number)
FROM Resultados a_tabla 
INNER JOIN (SELECT  new_table.guest_id
FROM Resultados new_table
GROUP BY new_table.guest_id
HAVING count(*) > 1) R ON (a_tabla.guest_id = new_table.guest_id)
ORDER BY a_tabla.guest_id
```

This querys will return the guest_id which has 1 or more rooms, if you change 1 for 2 this will return the guest_id which has more than 2 rooms.

I hope this will be helpful